# how to block INPUT eth0 but allow INPUT tun0?

Tags: iptables, openvpn

i want to block eth0 incoming traffic, with exceptions for 22,80,443 and allow all incoming traffic on tun0.

i have openvpn client config, with `route-nopull` and i add routes from a script with `route add -net 10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0` and on the server I have `client-to-client` and specify static ips with `client-config-dir`

I have found that ufw was messing up my config, so I am trying with traditional iptables rules. with the below rules, everything works as desired, except that I am wide open on the internet.

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -i tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -s EXTERNALIP/32 -o enp0s20f0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner 1002 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner 1002 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -s EXTERNALIP/32 -o enp0s20f0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner 1003 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner 1003 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -s EXTERNALIP/32 -o enp0s20f0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

when I try to nail it down with the following, I can no longer connect to 1194. I can still connect on ssh and http via eth0.

```
-A INPUT  -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
```

specifically, everything works until I add the last line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer using this configuration:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -i tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -m comment --comment "Block Broadcast INPUT (No log)" -j DROP
-A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -m comment --comment "Block Multicast INPUT (No Log)" -j DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -m comment --comment "Accept localhost Input" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 1194 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Allow the server to reply (related to lport)" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Allow the DNS1 to answer" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 8.8.4.4/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Allow the DNS2 to answer" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 10/min -m comment --comment "Log Input" -j LOG --log-prefix "FW DROP INPUT: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -i tun+ -m comment --comment "Accept TUN Input" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 10/min -m comment --comment "Log Forward" -j LOG --log-prefix "FW DROP FORWARD: " --log-level 7
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -s $EXTERNALIP -o $EXT_INT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner 1002 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner 1002 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -s $EXTERNALIP/32 -o $EXT_INT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m owner --uid-owner 1003 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -m owner --uid-owner 1003 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT ! -s $EXTERNALIP/32 -o $EXT_INT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -m comment --comment "Accept localhost Output" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -m comment --comment "Allow my computer to query the DNS server" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o $EXT_INT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o $EXT_INT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Allow my machine to connect to the DNS1" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.4.4/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Allow my machine to connect to the DNS2" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 10/min -m comment --comment "Log Output" -j LOG --log-prefix "FW DROP OUTPUT: " --log-level 7
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "Allow ping to Outside" -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o tun+ -m comment --comment "Accept TUN Output" -j ACCEPT
-A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
```